# C++ Crashlytics NDK crashes when used with header

Tags: android, android-ndk

I followed all the steps listed here: [crashlytics NDK Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports)

I copy pasted this file into my project: [crashlytics.h](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-crashlytics-ndk/src/main/jni/libcrashlytics/include/crashlytics/external/crashlytics.h)

I am calling it with the following:

```
#include "Crashlytics.h"
    
void NDKCrashlytics::logToCrashlytics(char *result) {
    firebase::crashlytics::Initialize();
    firebase::crashlytics::Log(result);
}
```

As soon as I call the method my app crashes and this is the log I get:

> E/AndroidRuntime(20818): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
> E/AndroidRuntime(20818): Process: com.insync.loopad, PID: 20818
> E/AndroidRuntime(20818): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find
> class "com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics" on path:
> DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64,
> /system/lib64]] E/AndroidRuntime(20818):  at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
> E/AndroidRuntime(20818):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> E/AndroidRuntime(20818):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) 2 (greylist,
> linking, allowed) D/libcrashlytics(20818): Initializing libcrashlytics
> version 3.0.0

I also saw this issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2245) but it is not solved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look into your APK. Can *you* find the class `com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics`? If it's not there, e.g. if it's renamed or optimized out by ProGuard, this will cause a crash that you complain about.

Comment: thanks, I decided not to use it because in the github issue it says that `the native API mechanism uses reflection to find certain classes; this fails if those classes are obfuscated in any way.` I will obfuscate my app and I assume that this will ruin this assumption if I am not mistaken, so in either case it will not work with my app

Comment: This is only relevant for the few classes that are provided by crashlitycs; there is little value in obfuscating the `com.google.firebase.crashlytics` package anyway. So, if you exclude it in your `proguard-rules.pro`, you can still use NDKCrashlytics and at the same time, obfuscate the sensitive classes of your app.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the wisdom. You are very correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On C++ side (replace *com_xxx_lib* with your package id):

```
#include "Crashlytics.h"
extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
    Java_com_xxx_lib_MyNativeActivity_jniCrashlyticsInit(JNIEnv * env ) {
        firebase::crashlytics::Initialize();
    }
}
void CrashlyticsLog(char const *msg)
{
    firebase::crashlytics::Log(msg);
}
```

On Java side:
call jniCrashlyticsInit() in onCreate() in your NativeActivity

```
public class MyNativeActivity extends NativeActivity
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("XXX");//your c++ library
    }
    public native void jniCrashlyticsInit();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        jniCrashlyticsInit();
    }
}
```

After that you can use firebase::crashlytics::Log(msg) in your C++ code.